# Raspberry PI Arduino communication

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi and Arduino connected via UART(TxRx) and I have a website HTML hosted on the rPi.
What do i need to do that when a button is pressed on the website a string would be sent to the arduino over UART.
I have already tried sending strings from rPi's terminal via command `echo test > /dev/ttyAMA0`, test being the string i want to send and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a CGI script on the rPi.  When the user's web browser goes to that page (or is directed to it by pushing a button) then the CGI scirpt will run on the rPi which can pipe data out the serial port.  Heres a random [CGI tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_cgi.htm) if it helps, but you should look at the docs for whatever webserver your running (probably [apache](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_cgi.htm)?)

Comment: Yes I am running an apache webserver.
And I forgot to  write that i have tried creating a .sh file that has the `echo` command in it.
This is my .sh script i created: #!/bin/sh echo 1 > /dev/ttyAMA0
This script sends the `1` to the /dev/ttyAMA (Arduino).
But somehow this didn't work for me...

Comment: Follow that apache link...  you have to configure apache to allow cgi scripts to run (and what folders contain CGI scripts).  You must also have a #!/path/to/shell at the top of your script so apache knows how to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am running an apache webserver.
And I forgot to  write that i have tried creating a .sh file that has the `echo` command in it.
This is my .sh script i created:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 1 > /dev/ttyAMA0
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>DzAnej Systems"
echo "</title></head><body>"
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url = http://192.168.1.3/dashboard.html\" />"
echo "</body></html>"
```

This script sends the `1` to the /dev/ttyAMA (Arduino)
and returns the user to the previous page...
The bottom part is working (return to the previous page) but the `echo` command is somehow not working...

Comment: This is not an answer; you should edit your question instead.

Comment: it seems your script isn't running...  just to be sure can you plug /dev/ttyAMA0 into your PC and see if the value is coming out but the arduino is ignoring it?  Change your CGI response to generate a page; something with a timestamp so you know that the CGI script ran when you clicked the button.